# powershell script to add data to a .xlsm file

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a excel file which is saved as a macro enabled sheet (.XLSM) as I have need to place some protections around the rows. I am now trying to figure out how to get my already running script to -append (I assume this means add data) to the file.

```
$user           = "User"
$pass1          = Read-Host "Enter Netscaler Password"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass1 -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $SecurePassword)
$today          = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
$Devicelist     = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\User\Documents\20221110\20221109_Citrix_inventory_Master1.csv' | 
                  Where-Object { $_.fqdn -match "nsr" -and 
                                 $_.State -match "Primary" -and 
                                 $_.Configuration_viewable_with_Techops_login -match "Yes" }

$result = foreach ($device in $Devicelist) {
    Write-Host "Attempting to connect to $($device.fqdn)"
    $session = Connect-NetScaler -Hostname $device.'IP Address' -Credential $Credential -PassThru 
    Get-NSLBVirtualServer | 
    Select-Object name, ipv46, port, curstate, @{Name = 'Device Name'; Expression = {$device.fqdn}}
    }

# now write out the csv file just once
$result | Out-File -Path "C:\Users\user\Documents\20221111\Netscaler VIPs per Cluster_test.xlsm" -force
```

At the moment I have it set to Out-File as Export-CSV didn't work as its not a CSV file. Unfortunately neither does Out-File but I am assuming that because I don't know how to specify which sheet to update/append.

I have also tried using the -Append command but that didn't appear to work either.

The reason I wish to append/add info to the existing file is we will be taking on more devices and it seems the sensible way of updating a list instead of having multiple copies of a file and then having to merge.

But maybe that would be a quicker way.

Questions

1. Is there a way to add info to an existing .xlsm file?
2. If so how do you specify the sheet to update?
3. if its not possible would a merger option work within excel if there is protections on the worksheet?

Kind regards

Comment: Appending to a excel file is quite easy with the ImportExcel module

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you. I found that this morning. It's a brilliant module.